# What does ようにする add here?

Tags: grammar, expressions

> 審判が笛を鳴らし、自らの左手首を右手でつかむ仕草をし、掲げるようにする。

What does ようにする add here? Why not just say 掲げる?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ように is "like" rather than "in order to". In other words, it indicates this gesture of a referee is something that resembles 掲げる but not the most typical 掲げる action. 手を掲げる usually means raising **one** hand **high** over one's head, as shown in [these image search results](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?p=%22%E6%89%8B%E3%82%92%E6%8E%B2%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%22). The gesture described in your sentence should be slightly different from this.